# Fill combobox from a column in jtable

Tags: java, swing, combobox

This is a school assigment and I am not allowed to use SQL. I have a JTable with the following columns:

`Cruise_name;Ship_name;Departure_location;Departure_date`

I am saving these items in a `.txt` file called `cruising.txt` which looks like this:

```
Atlantis;SOS FOR LOVE;Koper;1.1.2020;
Program;M.Hamilton;Neverland;1.1.2020;
Atlantis;Derpina;Lonely ;1.1.2020;
...
...
```

On a separate tab I need to populate a combobox with `Cruise_name` items I either get from that table directly (somehow) or make an ArrayList that reads the first item in every line from the `.txt` file. At this moment I don't know how to do either. I could really use some help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that you're gonna need to read that file anyway.
So my suggestion would be as follows: create a parser that reads from the file and creates objects of type Cruise (with your given attributes) - each line should result in another Cruise object. So the parser will return to you a list of Cruise objects.

Once you have this list, you can populate the table following [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and in the same time populate your combobox following [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like this... To fill up the combobox everytime i click on the tab.

```
private void jTabbedPane1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {

cbCruises.removeAllItems();

JTable table = this.tblCruises;

        int rowcount = table.getModel().getRowCount();
        for(int i = 0;i<rowcount;i++){
            cbCruises.addItem((String)table.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0));
        }}
```